# How to access a stream within a model created with MultiProvider?

Tags: flutter

I am using a MultiProvider at the root of my app, with a model which is initialised first in order that the DatabaseReference used by the StreamProvider exists.
I want to be able to pass 'context' into the MainModel, so that within MainModel I can access the stream using Provider.of(context)

I tried nesting the providers but this didn't help

```
// This is working, but how can I pass 'context' into MainModel?
// Within MainModel I want to be able to access the stream using Provider.of<MainModel>(context)...

main() async {
  MainModel model;
  await model.initialiseDatabase();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<MainModel>(builder: (context) => model),
      StreamProvider<Event>.value(stream: model.dbRef.onValue)
    ], child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MainModel with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseDatabase database;
  DatabaseReference dbRef;

  Future<Null> initialiseDatabase() async {
    database = await FirebaseDatabase();
    dbRef = await database.reference().child('products');
    return null;
  }}
```

Within the model I need a way to access the stream

Comment: That's not something provider allows – you'll need to manage it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Remi (great package btw!)
Can you offer me any advice on how else to achieve my end goal of accessing a stream within the model?

Comment: You can use `stream.listen`

Comment: You're right, of course